# Can I concat values in azure function binding template?

Tags: azure, binding, azure-functions

Is it possible to concat two URL parameter values to pass to a Table store template binding?

Something like...

```
[FunctionName("GetSomeValue")]
public static IActionResult Get
(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = ROUTE + "/{somevalue}/{someOtherValue}")]HttpRequest request,
    string somevalue,
    string someOtherValue,
    [Table(
        TABLE_NAME,
        ALL_HOSPITAL_PARTITION_KEY, 
        "{somevalue + '|' + someOtherValue}", //<--- This isn't acceptable
        Connection = "SomeValuesConnectionStringKey")]
        TableStoreDAO<SomeValueDAO> tableStoreRecord,
    ExecutionContext context,
    TraceWriter log
)
```

Here's the error that gets:

```
[3/16/2018 8:05:16 PM] A ScriptHost error has occurred
[3/16/2018 8:05:16 PM] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'SomeValueService.Get'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Invalid template '{somevalue + '|' + someOtherValue}'. Invalid template expression 'somevalue + '|' + someOtherValue.
```

I can't seem to find any documentation on the templating...  any references to that would be great to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer by simply guessing at what might be allowed.  This worked for me: `{somevalue}|{someOtherValue}`

Full example:

```
[FunctionName("GetSomeValue")]
public static IActionResult Get
(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = ROUTE + "/{somevalue}/{someOtherValue}")]HttpRequest request,
    string somevalue,
    string someOtherValue,
    [Table(
        TABLE_NAME,
        ALL_HOSPITAL_PARTITION_KEY, 
        "{somevalue}|{someOtherValue}",
        Connection = "SomeValuesConnectionStringKey")]
        TableStoreDAO<SomeValueDAO> tableStoreRecord,
    ExecutionContext context,
    TraceWriter log
)
```